# php operator == (sort of equality) and the integer 0

Tags: php, equality, comparison-operators

php, my dearest old frienemy.

ok, so i can come to terms with why the string '0' would be a falsie value. that's only fair seeing as how `'0'` is the same as `0` in a loosely typed language, and `0` is `false` in a loosely typed language. so this gives that `false` == `0` == `'0'`.

fine fine... BUT!! what is this all about?

```
<?php
    print "number of surprised persons: " . ('false' == 0);
```

the output is....

```
number of surprised persons: 1
```

how is this reasonable? am i the only one who's surprised by this? what am i failing to see?

further testing has proven that the integer 0 is equal (by operator ==) to

```
0        <-- integer
false    <-- boolean
null     <-- just.. you know, null
'0'      <-- string
''       <-- string
'false'  <-- string
'true'   <-- string
'null'   <-- string
```

naturally, i mostly use operator === to compare stuff. and now that i know about this, i'll have to adjust my programming of course, no question about that. but still! can someone shed some light pl0x?

Comment: `intval('false') ==> 0`, so the conversion is converting both values into integers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because, when you compare a string to an integer, they don't both get converted to strings, or to booleans - they get converted to *integers*. For PHP, when you think about it, this isn't strange at all (comparatively, I suppose).

```
'true' == 0
// is the same as
(int)'true' == 0
// is the same as
0 == 0
// is the same as
true
```

And this is true for any non-numeric string as well as the string `"0"`. The reason `1` is printed out is because the string version of `true` is `1` (and the string version of false is an empty string).

Answer (score 6):

As far as you're concerned about the output:

`('false' == 0)` = boolean `TRUE` = string `"1"`.

`echo` is triggering string context.

But from your comment below I've just seen, that you'd like to learn more about the comparison. Take a look what you do:

```
Example     Name     Result
$a == $b    Equal    TRUE if $a is equal to $b after type juggling.
```

so you are doing a non-strict comparison of a number with a string:

> If you compare a number with a string or the comparison involves numerical strings, then each string is converted to a number and the comparison performed numerically. ([REF](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php))

Note: Number, not integer as written in the accepted answer:

```
<?php
print "number of surprised persons: " . ('false' == 0.3 - 0.2 - 0.1);
```

Have fun.

Comment: i get that if 'false' was equal to 0, the number 1 would show up. but why would a string be equal to 0?

Comment: @davogotland: See my answer below.

Comment: why are people upvoting this answer? it's obvious that the person answering didn't even read my question all the way through.

Comment: @davogotland: I added the missing info for you, I actually read in your question you were surprised about the output. Anyway, even you've accepted an answer already, you might still find something interesting in my edited answer.

Answer (score 3):

false == 0 is true.  True as a string is '1' and you are doing an implicit conversion when you interpolate the value.

```
$a = true;
echo "$a"; #1
```

You can find a PHP truth table here.  I would just recommend the === comparator unless you have a good reason to use ==

http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

Comment: i hadn't seen that type comparison table before. they even state openly there that any string is equal to 0. why would someone want to implement a language like this? what are the benefits of it?

Comment: @davogotland: All languages (that I'm aware of) that are capable of converting a string to an integer (implicitly or explicitly) convert non-numeric strings to 0. It's not specific to PHP. Naturally, `intval("123bob")` is 123, but how would you suggest a language interpret intval("bob")?